# Visual studio 2019 cannot target 4.8 though it shows as installed on machine in control panel

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019

.net framework 4.8 shows as installed in control panel but visual studio 2019 is not showing it as a Target framework..tried to create new project with all possible template still visual studio is not showing target framework as 4.8 The machine is windows 7.Can any one please help?I have tried almost every possible option?

Comment: Click on the [Developer Pack](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net48) link.

Comment: Thanks...but why does it not target when it is already installed in the machine...

Answer (score 0):

you need to install .net framework 4.8 developer pack.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).